# How can I have all the integers in a string that has a combination of alphanumeric characters using RegEx

Tags: regex, numbers

For example I have: `1|2|3,4|5|6,7|8|10;`

How can I output it like this:

```
A: 1 2 3
B: 4 5 6
C: 7 8 10
```

And how can I do this:

```
Array A = {1,2,3}
Array B = {4,5,6}
Array C = {7,8,10}
```

Comment: is the patter always the same? `num | num | num , ....`

Comment: Hi vks: It's ODIN language. It follows the Microsoft regular expression..

Comment: Hi Uma Kanth, yes its pattern is num | num | num , num | num | num ; then it's end is semicolon (;)

Comment: How about splitting by `,` (comma) to get the list of rows and replace `|` (pipe) in each row with space?.......... for the second case you can split by comma.. then replace `|` with `,` and append `{` at the beginning and `}` at the end?

Comment: Yes that's the logic but how in regex?

Comment: @KylZ.SanAntonio: Regex cannot match discontinuous text, which means you should use `\d+\|\d+\|\d+` to extract your 3-digit pipe separated groups, and then `split` with a `\|` regex or just a literal `|` with appropriate methods. Where can we find Odin documentation?

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg = /(\d+)\|(\d+)\|(\d+)[,;]/g;
var str = "1|2|3,4|5|6,7|8|10;";
var index = 0;
str.replace(reg,function myfun(g,g1,g2,g3){
                    var ch = String.fromCharCode(65 + (index++));
                    return ch+": "+g1+" "+g2+" "+g3+"\n";
                });
```

the second case should update myfun return string:

```
"Array "+ch+" = {"+g1+","+g2+","+g3+"}\n";
```